redirect 301 site all urls www to non-www with https in htaccess
I can't redirect my all website pages, in www to non-www and https
I use Laravel 11
I try this, but it's just work for my home page:
RewriteCond %{HTTP:X-Forwarded-Proto} =http
RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301] 


Try this:
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On

# Force HTTPS
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]

# Redirect www to non-www
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.*)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ https://%1%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]

# Laravel standard rules follow
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
</IfModule>

